# Save a Tensorflow Model and Load it in Tensorflow.js

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, tensorflow.js

In my regular python code, I have a CNN implemented. I save it using model.save and produce some four files (checkpoint, meta, index, and some other file). However, I cannot load these four files directly to tensorflow.js. Here is the sample CNN:

```
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data, dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression

convnet = input_data(shape=[None, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1], name='input')

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL, FILTER_SIZE, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL*2, FILTER_SIZE, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = conv_2d(convnet, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL*4, FILTER_SIZE, activation='relu')
convnet = max_pool_2d(convnet, 2)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, FIRST_NUM_CHANNEL*8, activation='relu')
convnet = dropout(convnet, 0.7)

convnet = fully_connected(convnet, NUM_OUTPUT, activation='softmax')
convnet = regression(convnet, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=LR, loss='categorical_crossentropy', name='targets')

model = tflearn.DNN(convnet, tensorboard_dir='log')

train = train_data[:7000]
test = train_data[-1000:]


X = np.array([i[0] for i in train]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
Y = [i[1] for i in train]

test_x = np.array([i[0] for i in test]).reshape(-1,IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE,1)
test_y = [i[1] for i in test]


model.fit({'input': X}, {'targets': Y}, n_epoch=NUM_EPOCHS, validation_set=({'input': test_x}, {'targets': test_y}), 
    snapshot_step=500, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)

model.save(MODEL_NAME)
print('MODEL SAVED:', MODEL_NAME)
```

The last two lines of this code snippet is for saving the model. I can just load the model in a flask app but I want to port it to tensorflow.js. Can anyone give me a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: Here: https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-saved-model.html and here: https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html

Comment: Hi sebastian, I tried running this code but I'm not sure what are my parameters. ```tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_saved_model \
    --output_node_names='MobilenetV1/Predictions/Reshape_1' \
    --saved_model_tags=serve \
    /mobilenet/saved_model \
    /mobilenet/web_model```
The files that I have for now are 3cnn-layers.model, 3cnn-layers.index, checkpoint, and 3cnn-layers.data-0000-of-0001
What will my command be?

Comment: You got your model file? Then you can just use `tf.loadModel()` in your JavaScript

Comment: Thanks sebastian, but what file should I call for the loadModel?
```let model;
 (async function () {
  model = await tf.loadModel("cnnmodel/WHAT_FILE");
 })();```
Or should I put the file in a server?

Comment: .model I believe, but you could just try it out. And you have to prepend the storage type. (file:/// if you use nodejs, https:// if you want to load it over the internet). There are even more.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, after trying out the different files, I just read their documentation which has a step 1 ```Convert an existing TensorFlow model to TensorFlow.js Web format```. So I'm back with the issue on how to use the commands for ```tensorflowjs_converter ```.

Answer (score 1):

`tensorflowjs_converted` outputs among other files a weight file `weights_manifest.json` and a model topology file `tensorflowjs_model.pb`. To load this model in tensorflow.js, follow the steps outllined below.

- serve the folder containing the files using a server

```
// cd to the directory containing the files

// then launch the python server
python3 -m http-server

// or install and launch npm module http-server
npm install -g http-server
http-server --cors -c1 .
```

- create a js script to load the model

```
(async () => {
   ...
   const model = await tf.loadFrozenModel('http://localhost:8080/tensorflowjs_model.pb', 'http://localhost:8080/weights_manifest.json')
 })()
```

---

There is a difference between [loadModel](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.3/#loadModel) and [loadFrozenModel](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.13.3/#loadFrozenModel).

- `loadModel` is for loading model that were saved locally. The model could either be retrieved from the indexDB of the browser or from the localStorage. 
  Maybe it can be used to retrieve a model saved by another tensorflow API different than Js, but the user will be required to select the file by using `tf.io.browserFiles` ( I haven't tried it)
- `loadFrozenModel` is for loading model that are served by a server